# The app references non-public selectors in Payload/TabletJournal.app/TabletJournal: setImageName:

Tags: validation, reference, ios7, css-selectors, submission

I am updating my app to iOS7 due to some code rot... add subview for AlertView mainly.

That is all fixed, as well as a few other things.

The issue... I am getting this warning message when I attempt to validate the update:

What? I have searched through my code and there is nothing that matches this. The only thing close is "imageName" or "imageNamed", which is standard for a UIView.

I cannot believe that those are now part of a private API.

I have even commented out some code that is a part of some custom built security controller, that I thought might be offending... no difference. This same controller is also used in another app, that validated just fine.

So... I am at a loss to know what this is.

I have no 3rd-party Frameworks in the app. And, it has been on the store since 2010, without any changes since the last update in April of this year.

What the __ is going on???

Would appreciate any help.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that it is your UIAlertView issue.
Apple made some changes in the alertView, they have simplified it to be flat. So you can't add any subview to it. if you did somehow maybe thats the reason.

I was subclassing the UIAlertView and now I can't. Try to put the regular UIAlertView

Comment: Nope, changed that. I am not adding subviews any longer. Found that the textfield is invisible in iOS7. I have looked through the app and as I thought, there is no call for addSubview attached to any UIAlertView. It makes me wonder though... was there a change in how addSubview can be used?

Comment: Correction... not adding subviews to AlertView.